# Will a female L14-30R connector (4-prong) fit a male NEMA L5-30 plug?

Tags: electrical, cord-and-plug

I am trying to connect my battery generator to a [Reliance transfer switch](https://www.reliancecontrols.com/products/reliance-controls-pro-tran-2-portable-generator-transfer-switch-125v-30a-nema-l14-30-4-1p-15a-circuits-metal-gray-304a1). The transfer switch has a male NEMA L5-30 plug (4-prong)

Can I plug a female L14-30R connector (4-prong) into it?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the transfer panel installed and wired, you could find or make an adapter that would take one hot, neutral, and ground from the 14-30 plug side and present it on a 5-30 receptacle for the inlet. This may limit you to making use of only half of your generator's output (3000W vs. 6000W - 24A at 125V vs. 240V) because generators with 240V output generally require 120V loads to be distributed equally across the two halves of the output - not placed entirely on one of the legs.

If you haven't purchased that unit, get the R304A (no '1' at the end) instead, which will have a 14-30 inlet. Or, better yet, set up a real backup sub panel with an interlock for the feeds. Should be less expensive that the silly Reliance thing (especially if you make the sub panel the same brand/type as your main so that you can just move the backed-up circuit breakers over instead of buying new).